# iphone: open a list to choose from when clicking a row in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When clicking on the language setting on the iphone (Setting -> General -> International -> Language), a new table scrolls in from bottom to top. I would like to do the same in my app for several rows (with different rows in the opened table). Right now my only approach is to create a new view controller and fill it every time I click on a row. Is there a better way? Is there some sort of "child rows" per row?

thanks in advance...

Comment: What you are doing is exactly right.

Comment: thank you, I just wondered how much code is needed for that, on android its just a list...